# Turn Off Webstorm highlighting

Tags: html, angularjs, webstorm

HTML files in IDEA Webstorm highlight html tags and angular elements so the code is shining like a Christmas tree. I try off "highlighting level" to none, but this does not help...

How i can turn off this highlighting?

[Sample highlighting image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOmJE.jpg)

Comment: 1) Could you please post a screenshot with arrows pointing to a specific places; 2) If question is about places with green background -- please also post screenshot of what you see (should be a popup menu) when you invoke Alt+Enter when having caret placed in such place.

Comment: Vote for the "code is shining like a Christmas tree". This one spreads joy.

Answer (score 5):

1. Go to File -> Settings -> Editor -> Colors&Fonts -> **HTML**
2. Choose '**Tag**'
3. Then **uncheck 'Use inherited attributes'**
4. **Uncheck 'Background'**. That's it!!

[Here is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3Pls.jpg)

Comment: Now it's under `Editor` - `Color Scheme` - `HTML` - `Tag`

Answer (score 1):

Go to File->Settings->Editor->Inspections

There, you can control what to inspect, just untick the places you do not want to highlight

**UPDATE:**

1. Press Ctrl + Alt + Shift + H
2. There switch of the highlighting

Comment: I try this - i turn off all in HTML inspection, but it did not help.  Screenshot: http://joxi.ru/n2YY4qXf5vev26.jpg

Comment: yes about this i type in first message: "I try off "highlighting level" to none, but this does not help..." still all highlights...